# How to pass value from HTML Textbox to JQgrid URL Parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have MVC3 asp.net project. 
I create controller function with some parameters,
the question is how can I pass the value from Textbox to Jqgrid?

I want to something like:

```
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
        url: '@url.content("~/")MyController/MyFunction?Parameter1=valueFromTextBox'
...
```

I tried to insert with

```
$("#TextBox").attr("value")
```

but it doesn't work
any have idea?

thanks

vantian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better use `postData` parameter having function (method):

```
$("#list1").jqGrid({
    url: '<%= Url.Content("~/MyController/MyFunction") %>',
    postData: {
        Parameter1: function() { return $("#TextBox").val(); }
    },
    ...
});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for details.